# What high school classes are used in fluid and thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I want to become an aerospace engineer and use the physics of fluid dynamics and thermodynamics. I'm going into 9th grade soon and finished algebra 2 in 8th grade. What classes should I take?

Someone I was talking to said differential calculus, vector algebra, rotational dynamics - advanced mechanics and regular Newtonian physics, Mechanics. Are these classes in school? Thanks!

Comment: *"Are these classes in school?"* Depends on where you live and your school. I couldn't even choose which types of physics/Mathematics I would like to do in school.

Answer (score 0):

Whether these things are taught in high school probably depends on what coutry you are in.

My (UK) math teacher took our university-bound class through  L. M. Milne-Thomson's "Theoretical Hydrodynamics" in my last year of secondary school. It was accessible to those of us who were comfortable with calculus, interesting in itself, and a good intro to the more advanced vector calculus we used  at college. I still have a copy. It's available from Dover at about $25.

Thomson also wrote "Theoretical Aerodynamics" which includes discussion of rocket nozzles which is a good blend of mechanics and thermo.

Thomson is a good expositor and
even if these books are a bit hard for a high-schooler, they give you a flavour of what you will want to learn for aerospace engineering.